# Преобразование типов из data класса в recyclerView

Tags: android, json, kotlin, recyclerview, mvvm

Имеется  JSON response:

```
{
    "response" : [
        {
            "f_name"    : "иВан",
            "l_name"    : "ИваноВ",
            "birthday"  : "1987-03-23",
            "specialty" : [{
                "specialty_id" : 101,
                "name"  : "Менеджер"
            }]
        },
        {
            "f_name"    : "Петр",
            "l_name"    : "петроВ",
            "birthday"  : null,
            "specialty" : [{
                "specialty_id" : 101,
                "name"  : "Менеджер"
            }]
       }
    ]
}
```

и соответствующий data class  в модели:

```
data class Response(
    @SerializedName("avatr_url")
    val avatrUrl: String,
    val birthday: String,
    @SerializedName("f_name")
    val fName: String,
    @SerializedName("l_name")
    val lName: String,
    val specialty: List<Specialty>
)
```

Требуется вывести список всех профессий в RecyclerView, в классе ViewModel делаю transformation.map для полученной liveData:

```
class SpecialtyListViewModel : ViewModel() {
    val employeesInfo = liveData {
        val data = Employee.repository.getEmployeesInfo()
        emit(data)
    }
    val specialties = Transformations.map(employeesInfo) {
        it.response
    }
    val specialtyList = Transformations.map(specialties) {
        it[0]
    }
 }
```

Во фрагменте подписываюсь на liveData и вызываю адаптер RecyclerView, в который нужно добавить аргументом приведенный тип liveData именно для specialtyList:

```
class SpecialtyListFragment : Fragment(), SpecialtyListAdaapter.Listener {

    companion object {
        fun newInstance() = SpecialtyListFragment()
    }

    private lateinit var viewModel: SpecialtyListViewModel
    lateinit var specialtyListAdaapter: SpecialtyListAdaapter

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
       viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(SpecialtyListViewModel::class.java)
        val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.specialty_list_fragment, container, false)
        root.specialtyListRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        viewModel.specialties.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
           specialtyListAdaapter = SpecialtyListAdaapter(it, this)
           specialtyListRecyclerView.adapter = specialtyListAdaapter
        })
        return root
    }
}
```

Получаю от IDE ошибку приведения типов:

```
Type mismatch.
Required:
List<Specialty>
Found:
List<Response>!
```

В данном случае сам класс Response является Listом, а поле name является элементом списка specialty вложенного в каждый элемент списка Response. Хотелось бы выяснить как корректно сформировать список для передачи??...Может через map или же к примеру нужно создать новый список, обращаясь к liveDate , например:

```
fillSpecialtyList(): List<Specialty> {
        val specialtyList = arrayListOf<Specialty>()
        for (....)
        return specialtyList
    }
```

???

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Тип `EmployeesInfo` покажите, без него непонятно откуда несоответствие типов берется. И где ошибку IDE показывает, в `SpecialtyListViewModel`?

Comment: data class EmployeesInfo(
    val response: List<Response>
)

Comment: Несоответствие типов в SpecialtyListFragment, когда адаптеру нужно дать в аргумент список List<Specialty>

Answer (score 0):

Т.е. получается класс EmployeesInfo это список типа Response:

```
{
    "response" : [
        {
            "f_name"    : "иВан",
            "l_name"    : "ИваноВ",
            "birthday"  : "1987-03-23",
            "specialty" : [{
                "specialty_id" : 101,
                "name"  : "Менеджер"
            }]
        },
        {
            "f_name"    : "Петр",
            "l_name"    : "петроВ",
            "birthday"  : null,
            "specialty" : [{
                "specialty_id" : 101,
                "name"  : "Менеджер"
            }]
       }
    ]
}
```

А в конструкторе класса Response есть поле specialty являющееся судя по квадратным скобкам тоже  списком (в нем 1-й элемент specialty_id, 2-й name). А мне нужно как раз сформировать список из этих name из всех объектов массива Response и дать их адаптеру, чтоб они в RecyclerView отобразились..

```
data class Response(
    @SerializedName("avatr_url")
    val avatrUrl: String,
    val birthday: String,
    @SerializedName("f_name")
    val fName: String,
    @SerializedName("l_name")
    val lName: String,
    val specialty: List<Specialty>
)

data class Specialty(
    val name: String,
    @SerializedName("specialty_id")
    val specialtyId: Int
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Если в SpecialtyListViewModel написать функцию для преобразования:

```
fun convertSpecialtyClass(response: List <Response>): List <Specialty>{
        val newList = mutableListOf<Specialty>()
        response.forEach {
            newList += Specialty(it.specialty[0].name.toString(), 1)
        }
        return newList
    }
```

если ее вызвать фрагменте и сказать об этом адаптеру (что видимо не является правильным):

```
class SpecialtyListFragment : Fragment(), SpecialtyListAdaapter.Listener {

    companion object {
        fun newInstance() = SpecialtyListFragment()
    }

    private lateinit var viewModel: SpecialtyListViewModel
    lateinit var specialtyListAdapter: SpecialtyListAdapter
    lateinit var specialties:List<Specialty>

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
       viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(SpecialtyListViewModel::class.java)
        val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.specialty_list_fragment, container, false)
        root.specialtyListRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        specialties = viewModel.convertSpecialtyClass(viewModel.listResponse.value!!)            
        specialtyListAdapter = SpecialtyListAdapter(specialties, this)
        specialtyListRecyclerView.adapter = specialtyListAdapter
        return root
    }
```

на выходе получаем на Runtime ошибку:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.employee.ui.specialtylistfragment.SpecialtyListFragment.onCreateView(SpecialtyListFragment.kt:34)
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).